# OutOfMemoryError in renderMergedOutputModel - returning large objects from a Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, csv, out-of-memory

I have some code in a Spring MVC app that queries a database and builds a CSV file from the result set. The general idea looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping
(value = "/path/to/the/data")
public ModelAndView getDataAsCsv(...) {
    List<RowObject> bigObject; // can be > 1GB in memory
    bigObject = dataService.getData(...);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dataCsvView");
    mav.addObject("bigObject", bigObject);
    return mav;
}
```

Then we have a `DataCsvView` class which extends `AbstractView` and overrides `renderMergedOutputModel`. Just about the first thing it does is:

```
List<RowObject> bigObject = (ArrayList<RowObject>)model.get("bigObject");
```

And then it proceeds to iterate over this thing, convert each line to a CSV string, and write it to the `BufferedWriter` that comes from Spring's `HttpServletResponse#getWriter` method.

**The Problem**

If the data set is large enough (more than ~500k rows), that `bigObject` thing will be > 1GB in memory. As soon as `renderMergedOutputModel` is called and it tries to get the object out of the model, the app throws OutOfMemoryError. Or maybe the error is happening before `renderMergedOutputModel` is called. Either way, the act of putting the object into the `mav` map is not the failure point (I've checked).

One solution is to increase the memory available to our Tomcat process, but that's obviously not very scalable... (these `bigObject`s will likely get larger in the future)

What's the "right" way to do this in Spring MVC? Is there a nice architecture that would let us stream the response without bottling it all up in memory first?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `View` implementation for that, but write to the `OutputStream` myself and I would do this streaming instead of loading everything into memory. How to do this depends on your underlying technology, but using a `JdbcTemplate` I would implement a `RowCallBackHandler` which write to the `Writer` directly (maybe by passing it into a service method).

```
public class CvsWritingRowCallbackhandler implements RowCallbackHandler {

    private final Writer writer;

    public CvsWritingRowCallbackhandler(Writer writer) {
        this.writer=writer;
    }

    public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {      
        String line = // do something with current row to create a Comma Seperated line
        writer.write(line);
                    writer.flush();
    }

}

public void someServiceMethod(final Writer writer) {
    getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new CvsWritingRowCallbackhandler(writer)); 
}

@RequestMapping
public void requestHandlingMethod(Writer writer) {
    someService.someServiceMethod(writer);
}
```

Or stream the CSV data to a file, during loading and then create a view which streams this file to the client (that way you don't have to have everything in memory all the time). You only need to pass around the filename that way.